# How can i convert this nonfunctional scala code with immutable members to an elegant solution?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, immutability

How to avoid mutable index and make this more elegant?I know Null has to be changed with Option , i am just curious about the answers.

```
class Person(val name: String, val department: String)

var people = Array(new Person(“Jones”, “Marketing”), new Person(“Smith”, “Engineering”))
var engineer: Person = null
var index = 0

while (index < people.length) {

  if (people(index).department == “Engineering”) 
    engineer = people(index)

  index = index + 1


}
println(engineer.name + “ is an engineer”)
```

Comment: This code contains bug (infinite loop). Do you want to get this bug in functional code?

Comment: Maybe it would help if you could describe in words what the code-snippet is actually supposed to do.

Comment: So you want to print last engineers on the list name? Or any? Or first?

Comment: Not a real question: has been cut and pasted from this job advert on StackOverflowCareers: http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/79585/scala-developer-typesafe-stack-scala-play-property-partner Perhaps OP should follow their advice: "if you had to Google anything to do this, it might not be the right time for you to apply."

Comment: who cares about applying?

Comment: This code prints the last person's name whose department is engineering , but output is not important. It can print all people with engineering department, it's up to you. I know how to correct it my way, but i just wanted to know about other perspectives.

Comment: @LuigiPlinge Good catch. Although, to be fair, it is a real question.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Person(val name: String, val department: String)

val people = Array(new Person(“Jones”, “Marketing”), new Person(“Smith”, “Engineering”))

// Option[ Person ]... None if no Person satisfy this condition... Some( p ), if Person p is the first Person to satisfy the condition.
val personOption = people.find( p => p.department == "Engineering" )

personOption match {
    case Some( p ) => println( " Found one engineer - " + p )
    case None => println( "No engineer" )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would refactor:

```
// Refactored into a case class, since it's a simple data container
case class Person(name: String, department: String)

// Using the case class convenience apply method to drop `new` 
val people = Array(Person(“Jones”, “Marketing”), Person(“Smith”, “Engineering”))

// Selects all the engineers. You could add `.headOption` to get the first. 
val engineers = people.filter(_.department == "Engineering")

// Functional way of iterating the collection of engineers
// Also, using string interpolation to print
for (engineer <- engineers) println(s"${engineer.name} is an engineer.")
```

Alternatively, you could use `collect` to filter and pick the name:

```
// Collect is kind of a like a handy filter + map
val engineerNames = people.collect {
  case Person(name, "Engineering") => name
}

for (name <- engineerNames) println(s"$name is an engineer.")
```

One last tip, if your departments are some finite set of fixed options, you should probably also consider making it a type:

```
sealed trait Department
case object Engineering extends Department
case object Marketing extends Department
// ... for each valid department
```

And then you can match on identity, rather than value. This lets you rely on the type system instead of constantly having to validate strings (known to some as [stringly-typed programming](http://blog.codinghorror.com/new-programming-jargon/)). Best practice is to validate your data as early as possible into types, deal with it as typed data, and then only convert back to string for exporting data back out of your system (e.g. printing to screen, logging, serving via API).

Comment: thkan you, it's so instructive and explanatory. By the way, a double quote is missing after  Engineering.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find the last engineer in the array, you would probably use:

```
case class Person(val name: String, val department: String)

val people = Array(Person(“Jones”, “Marketing”), Person(“Smith”, “Engineering”))

def findLastEngineer(l: Seq[Person]) : Option[Person] =  
  people.foldLeft(None) { 
    case (previousOpt, eng) => if (eng.department == "Engineering") Some(eng) else previousOpt
  }
}

println(findLastEngineer(people).map(_.name).getOrElse("Not found"))
```

Comment: Or just `people.filter(Person.department.equals("Engineering")).last`

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:

```
case class Person(name: String, department: String)

val people = List(Person("Jones", "Marketing"), Person("Smith", "Engineering"))

val engineers = people.filter { person:Person => person.department == "Engineering" }

engineers.map { engineer: Person => println(engineer.name + " is an engineer") }
```

Try to use functions to transform your types in others. Usually we use map/reduce/filter functions to do this.

Comment: right, functions map/reduce/filter already deal with all elements of the collection, so we don't have to bother with mutable indexes

Answer (score 0):

You can use `find` to find first:

```
people
  .find { _.department == "Engineering" }
  .foreach { engineer => println(engineer.name + " is an engineer") }
```

or `filter` to find all:

```
people
  .filter { _.department == "Engineering" }
  .foreach { engineer => println(engineer.name + " is an engineer") }
```

By the way you can fix your code just by moving increment operation outside the `if` block:

```
if (people(index).department == "Engineering") {
  engineer = people(index)
  // index = index + 1
}
index = index + 1
```

After that you should check `engineer` for `null`, because your array may not contain a `Person` for your condition.

So it looks like you want to find last `Person`, thus you can use:

```
people
  .foldLeft(None: Option[Person])((r, p) =>
    if (p.department == "Engineering") Some(p) else r)
  .foreach { engineer => println(engineer.name + " is an engineer") }
```

Also after avoiding all `var`s you can also change your `Array` (which is mutable structure) to `List` (by default scala.collection.immutable.List)